# блочная модель или как контейнер не хочет быть контейнером

Tags: html, css

есть такая структура

```css
 .event_border {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -o-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
   float: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 30px 8px 10px 10px;
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .event_image {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<div class="event_container" id="all_events">
  <div class="event_border" id="event1">
    <div class="event_image">
      <img src="Без имени-1.jpg" />
      <div class="event_note">
        <div id="event_calendar_left">Left</div>
        <div id="event_calendar_count">#</div>
        <div id="event_calendar_days">Days</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event_close" id="close_event1">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="event_date">19 December - 20 November</div>
      <div class="event_description">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_border" id="event2">
    <div class="event_image">
      <img src="Без имени-2.jpg" />
      <div class="event_note">
        <div id="event_calendar_left">Left</div>
        <div id="event_calendar_count">#</div>
        <div id="event_calendar_days">Days</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event_close" id="close_event2">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="event_date">19 December - 20 November</div>
      <div class="event_description">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

собственно родительский блок `class="event_container"`по непонятным мне причинам не вмещает в себя блоки `class="event_border"`, а по коду элементов отображается где то сверху, не имеющим никаких размеров. Нужно что бы он вмещал в себя именно те два блока , родителем которым он им и является

Comment: без css невозможно что-либо сказать

Comment: добавьте css, подозреваю что у вложенных элементов задан `float` либо position:absolute или fixed

Comment: У вас id `event_calendar_left`, `event_calendar_count` и `event_calendar_days` повторяются для каждого event. id  должны быть уникальны на странице. Вряд ли это создает описанную проблему, но исправить надо...

Comment: добавил css в вопрос

Comment: вся вина во `float: left;` для `.event_border`

Comment: @Grundy прав. Попробуйте исправить на `display: inline-block;`

Comment: ну или можно еще в сторону `display:flex` посмотреть

Comment: поправил, работает, но теперь вместо 4 блоков в ряд получилось 3 в ряд и 1 перенесся

Comment: хоть и задано 
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){
    .event_border{
        width: 25%;
    }
}

Comment: не хватило ширины скорее всего

Comment: `.event_border{ width: 25%; }` вы еще учтите пробел между элементами, вот четвертый и не вмещается

Comment: а ведь да, спасибо всем за ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Если float: left необходим, то для исправления нулевого размера родительского блока добавьте ему свойство **overflow: hidden**.